# Apple sign in com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1000

Tags: ios

I've just downloaded the apple sign up sample project from apple documentation website , but when i try to use my apple id to login using the apple [demo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple) app i am getting this error :

```
[core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7089 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=com.example.xxxxx.juice} 
Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1000 "(null)"
```

The entiltment already added

[image]

my app rejected becouse of same problem , apple review team is testing on ipad simulator , any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

**Usually, this error appears if you are not signed to iCloud through iOS simulator, after you signed in it disappears.**

After, you should make sure that you use iOS 13 version, not 14 or 15, but 13. Otherwise, it will be infinite loading on you try to login via apple id